# how to alert each values from json array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

i have this json array that looks like the following:

```
[
    {"fname":"name1","id":"1"},
    {"fname":"name2","id":"2"},   
    {"fname":"name3","id":"3"},
    {"fname":"name4","id":"4"}
]
```

i want to alert fname for each. so will alert for times.
first time "name1", second time "name2", 3rd time "name3", and 4th time "name4".

how could i do that in jquery? i tried

```
$.each(arrofobject, function(index, val) {
    alert(val.category);
});
```

however its not working

Comment: The code you have shown is perfectly alright. Please show your full code. The error might be in some other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arrofobject = [{"fname":"name1","id":"1"},{"fname":"name2","id":"2"}, {"fname":"name3","id":"3"},{"fname":"name4","id":"4"}];

$.each(arrofobject, function(index, val) {
    alert('Name: '+ val.fname);
    alert('ID: '+val.id);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/d9hjrhp4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate array

```js
var array = [{
  "fname": "name1",
  "id": "1"
}, {
  "fname": "name2",
  "id": "2"
}, {
  "fname": "name3",
  "id": "3"
}, {
  "fname": "name4",
  "id": "4"
}];

array.forEach(function(v) {
  alert(v.fname);
});
```

Problem with your code : there is no `category` object property , so you need to use `fname` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var arrofobject = [{"fname":"name1","id":"1"},{"fname":"name2","id":"2"},   {"fname":"name3","id":"3"},{"fname":"name4","id":"4"}];

$.each(arrofobject, function(index, val) {
    alert(val.id+" : "+val.fname);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery way,

```
var arr = [
    {"fname":"name1","id":"1"},
    {"fname":"name2","id":"2"},   
    {"fname":"name3","id":"3"},
    {"fname":"name4","id":"4"}
];

$.each(arr, function(k, v){
     alert(v.id +' ==> '+ v.fname);
})
```

Comment: And the existing `way` is not jQuery? :)